# Edit powershell script to merge 2 docx into one PDF

Tags: powershell, pdf

i have found this script online. It converts docx files to pdf. The thing is, it creates one pdf for each docx. I need to edit this script, to merge 2 docx files into one single PDF file. I have zero knowledge of powershell, but i know batch in linux.

```
$documents_path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

$word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

Get-ChildItem -Path $documents_path -Filter *.doc? | ForEach-Object {

    $document = $word_app.Documents.Open($_.FullName)

    $pdf_filename = "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.BaseName).pdf"

    $document.SaveAs([ref] $pdf_filename, [ref] 17)

    $document.Close()
}

$word_app.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the design of the script you are using.

Use the more direct approach by merging the .docx files first, then convert to PDF. This means you have to understand the MSWord object model and how to code for it. You're going to have to pick a starting .docx the append other word data to the end.

So, do a search for how to merge Word files. Get that worked out, then you can just use PowerShell to make them .pdfs.

With zero knowledge of PowerShell, you should really take a few quick online training session to get an handle on it all, before you get yourself in a very frustrating position.

Go to the Microsoft Virtual Academy and YouTube and do a search for 'beginning PowerShell'